# Multi culture web sites

Tags: language-agnostic

How can I create a website using Tamil Font instead of English?

Comment: Research Globalization and Localization techniques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use Tamil by creating a site that uses UTF-8 as an encoding. Here's a web site that explains how:

http://tlt.its.psu.edu/suggestions/international/bylanguage/tamilchart.html